# $.ajax not working;product id is coming in method add_to_cart(id), i have confirmed by alerting

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
    function add_to_cart(id){
        alert("data"+id);
        var prod_id=id;

        $.ajax({
            url:"cart2.php",
            method:"POST",
            dataType: 'text',
            data:{'prod_id':prod_id},
            success:function (data) {         
                alert("success");
                console.log(data);
            }

        });

    }   // end method add_to_cart()
```

**PHP File**

```
<?php

    $product_id = $_POST['prod_id'];
    echo $product_id;

?>

<a href="" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart" id="<?php echo $row['product_id']; ?>" onClick="return add_to_cart(this.id);"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Add to cart</a>
```

product id is coming in method add_to_cart(id), i have confirmed by alerting, but this is not going to cart2.php and not returning from there.

Comment: Try to check in your developer tool if you are posting the prod_id

Comment: Thank you every one for your comments & answers, the same code is working on Chrome but not on firefox

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    $.ajax({
            url:"cart2.php",
            type:"POST",
            data:'prod_id='+prod_id,
            success:function (data) {         
                alert("success");
                console.log(data);
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

try after change dataType to "json" instead of "text".

Comment: in cart2.php, i'll get prod_id using _POST or some other method??

Comment: The code in php file is i think OK, all you need to change dataType of ajax.
and you can also remove dataType field from ajax call.